# Parsing XML using XSLT?

Tags: asp.net, xml

How can I parse a XML document using XSLT? May be I am wrong, Is it possible to parse a XML document using XSLT?

Here is XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<cart>
  <item id="1">
    <name>Tyres</name>
    <cost>20</cost>
  </item>
  <item id="2">
    <name>Front Glass</name>
    <cost>30</cost>
  </item>
  <item id="3">
    <name>Vanity Mirror</name>
    <cost>10</cost>
  </item>
  <item id="4">
    <name>Brake Pads</name>
    <cost>50</cost>
  </item>
  <item id="5">
    <name>Brake Oil</name>
    <cost>40</cost>
  </item>
</cart>
```

and the XSLT page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="shopping_cart">
      <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cart"/>
      </root>        
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="cart">
    <cart>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="cost">
        <xsl:value-of select="cost"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

    </cart>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any way to do that? Please guide as I don't know much about parsing concept.

Comment: What do you mean "Parse an XML file using XSLT"? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well I want to get specific values from XML document using XSLT and then manipulate them in the code.

Comment: XSLT is for transforming XML data into another text file.  If you want to use the data in your application I would suggest LINQ to XML or XmlSearilizer.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one XML document used by the stylesheet, the normal mechanism is to make it the "principal input document". Depending on the API to your processor, you can typically supply the source document in either parsed or unparsed form; if you supply it in unparsed form (for example as an InputStream) it will automatically be parsed and presented to the stylesheet as a tree of nodes.

If your stylesheet uses multiple documents, you can access (and parse) the secondary input documents using the document() function.